# How to unit test functions inside componentwillmount using jest and enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a function inside componentWillMount.

component

```
componentWillMount = () => {
const {
  agents,
  match
} = this.props;
this.edit = false;
this.agent = {};
if (match.params.id) {
  this.edit = true;
  this.agent = getAgent(agents, match.params.id);
  if ("undefined" === typeof this.agent) {
    push("/agents");
  }
}
resetStatusMessage();
formResetError();
};

render = () => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const agent = this.agent;
    this.avatar = agent.avatar;
    ...........................
}
```

I'am trying to test whether the getAgent function is called.And i also need to check the resetStatusMessage() and formResetError() were called.

Tests:

```
it("should call getAgent when mounted", () => {
const match = {
params: {
  id: "1"
}
},
agents ={
loading: false,
byId : {
  1:{
    firstName: "abc",
    lastName: "xyz"
  }
},
avatar: "avatarUrl"
};
let mockGetAgent = jest.fn();
const store = configureStore();
const wrapper = mount(
<Provider store={store}>
  <AgentForm match={match} getAgent={mockGetAgent}/>
</Provider>
);
expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
expect(mockGetAgent).toBeCalled();
});
```

But my test failed with this message :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined
```

How can i solve this issue?In my react project am using jest and enzyme for testing.am new to react and enzyme.Any help will really appreciable.

Comment: where are `getAgent()` and the other functions defined? It looks like you've created a mock function but then haven't passed it in to the component

Comment: updated in code.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I didn't mean you need to pass it in as a prop. This will only work if the component normally receives the `getAgent` function as a prop.

I'm guessing that `getAgent` is a function defined within the same file as your component but outside of the component itself, and that you're only exporting the component?

If this is the case, when you mount the component it will look for `getAgent` within its scope and try to call it. At the moment, you've created a function called `mockGetAgent` but the component never makes a call to `mockGetAgent`. I think what you need to do is call your mock `getAgent` and get it to return something (e.g. An object that looks like one of your agents) so that this.agent isn't undefined

Also, a couple of notes on unit testing:

1. you should try to test your components in isolation. Here you're testing both `Provider` and `AgentForm` at the same time, but given that they each do specific things you should just try to test they're each doing their own job.
2. it's not very effective to test a component by checking that every function it uses gets called. You should try to check that the job the function does has been completed. E.g. if the `getAgent` function gets info about agents so that it can be rendered then you should check that your wrapper contains that info, rather than checking that `getAgent` was called

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  As you suggested like i create an object(agent). Like this:                                                                            
        let agent = { firstName: "test",
        lastName: "mock",
        email: "test@test.com"} ;                                                             
       agent = mockGetAgent(agents, match.params.id);                         
      Did you mean like this?

Comment: yep the agent object looks fine but try mocking getAgent like this: const getAgent = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(agent);